# Android - ListView with different sizes images in items makes the ListView jerk

Tags: android, listview

How do I make listview run smoothly when the items have images with various heights?
Using recycling and calculating the ImageView dimension in the getView when I go up the list jerks horribly and skips parts
Thank you

Comment: What layouts are you using? How are your cells? Do you know about scaleType?

Comment: Did you find an answer? I do have the same problem. I tried setting the ImageView height in the getView method, but did not work

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Custom Listview With fixed item Height at that time for ImageView you need to use :

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
```

Using this Image which is any size can be Fit to listView Item size

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Image Will be Fixed

Answer (score 0):

Don't change the view size on the `getView()` method. Instead override the Adapter methods `getViewTypeCount()` and `getItemViewType()`.

If you use these methods right, returning a different number for different size views, Android will recycle the right view for you on `getView()`. This way the list is measured correct and the list will scroll smoothly.

Comment: The problem is that there could be an infinite number of possible types because images are from a webservice and there could be any possible height, can this be a problem?

Comment: You could limit to a few sizes and scale the image to match those size.